# Why am I getting a “hover is not defined” error in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hover

What’s going on? It says that “hover is not defined”, but in my jsFiddle, the code works fine:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="hover(1);">click</a>
<div id="1"></div>

<script type="text/javscript">
function hover(x) {
    var id = x;
    var hoverBubble = document.getElementById(id);
    hoverBubble.innerHTML = "hello";
}
</script>
```

Comment: **What** is saying "hover is not defined"?

Comment: Not sure if related, but you've misspelt "javascript" in the script type parameter.

Comment: <script type="text/javscript">???try this for HTML5 - <script>. also i recommend checking that the window is loaded prior to javascript execution by doing the following - "window.onload = function() { CODE HERE };

Comment: Older browsers do not support ids that start with numbers, it is not part of the HTML4 spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

That is misspelled. It should be `javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```